# How to copy existing Blob into Azure Media Services using the CLI

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services, azure-cli

I'm looking for a way to copy an existing Blob from an Azure "Storage account" to an Azure "Media Services account" using the CLI or the portal.

There seems to be plenty of documentation for Windows centric platforms- but nothing for 'nix or Mac users.

Side note: Why is there an assumption that I would want to do this via code? (which btw also seems to require a Windows platform)?  I've got a large video (e.g., larger then the 200MB limit for portal upload) - I want to load it into media service - why is that so difficult?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but from a quick glance at the portal and testing it, it seems like you can just upload your video to the (classic) Storage Account created with Azure Media Services, using any tool that can handle Azure Blob Storage, such as the cross platform [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.io). After that you can simply select that video in the portal under upload content > from storage. Note that it only works with classic storage accounts.

Comment: Thank you for the note about Cyberduck - I'll look into it. As I stated, I actually was able to finally get large files (in this case mp4) into a Storage account container. The problem now is that once in there, they are NOT showing up in the portal upload content window you've noted.  A bug in the portal perhaps?  I don't know. But it doesn't work as one might intuitively guess.

Comment: I've actually gone through this step-by-step and it worked for me. Are you sure that you've uploaded the file into a classic storage account?

Comment: I'm very sure... I just added a screen shot graphic to help describe the environment.  I'd really like to see how you made this work!

Comment: That is odd, I cannot see anything I did differently. Have you tried uploading the files to the storage container that came with the Media Services account? (idmmediaaccount I'd guess from your screenshot).

Comment: Well... Yes, I did; but to clarify; storage accounts don't "come with" a Media service account (to my knowledge). A storage accounts gets created if you upload a file (small enough to upload via the portal) into Media services. 

And I had the same idea you suggested; I tried uploading into that... Successful - but again, the file did not show up in the "Upload from storage" dialog box

Answer (score 0):

You can upload you media to any blob storage account 
Then when you want to create a media services asset  you can copy it to the Media Services blob storage and create an asset using the blob you moved.

Unfortunately at the moment Azure Media Service is not supported VIA Azure Cli 
But there is a power shell support 
See this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-manage-with-powershell/)

You can write some code and do everything using the SDK 
There are SDKs for .Net , Java, Python, Node, Php and more...

Comment: How?  I am not looking for a way to manage Media Service assets from the CLI. 

I simply want to move a blob that resides in a container that resides in a Storage account.  And I DO NOT WANT TO write code to move a single file.  If that is what is required using Azure - I think Amazon Web Services is a far better platform independent solution.

Comment: You can use Power Shell script (no code)
Or AzCopy (CLI) - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/

Comment: ummmm no... As I stated in the original post, I am looking for a non-windows dependent solution (e.g., Mac)

Comment: You can use Azure-CLI https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-azure-cli/ and the "azure storage blob upload" command for that to run on mac

Comment: Thanks Nava - that is what I thought and hoped would work too. As indicated in the beginning, it does NOT work.
That in fact is the issue here.  I've uploaded a video into a storage container. (and verified that it is there)
Then from media services screens, attempted to do what you've described. The Blob is not visible from Media Services (see screen shots above)

Answer (score 0):

To be visible in the Azure Media Service storage explorer UI, your files need to add a valid extension, as answered here : [Azure not displaying blobs within container in Storage Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403739/azure-not-displaying-blobs-within-container-in-storage-account)

Hope this helps,

Julien