# Azure not displaying blobs within container in Storage Account

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I've finally been able to upload two videos as blobs into a storage account container. I can see the blobs from the portal when I drill down into Storage > storage account name > Container > container name.

I can also see them from the CLI with the command "*storage blob list*".

However

When I attempt to upload the content into my Media service account - I select upload content from storage, Select the Account, then the container... and I get the erroneous message that there are no blobs

Clearly, there are - but they are not showing up. Any clues?

(see attached screen shots)

[image: Screen shots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with Azure Media Services Explorer ? It's a very nice tool to work with Azure Media Services without any line of code !

You can download it directly from GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer

**EDIT :** ok, I think I have found why the blob list is empty. I did not saw that your two files have no extensions. I have just repro your issue with a file without extension, as you can see below:

[image: repro]

To work with Azure Media Services encoders, your files need to have valid extensions.

Hope this helps,

Julien

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately, it depends on a Windows environment.  I need a platform independent solution because I developing on a Mac platform. 

I'm beginning to believe that Azure really has not matured to the point of being a viable alternative to Amazon Web Services. If Azure can not be leveraged and managed without Windows, it really is not up to par. 

Further, documentation for managing Media Content is simply inaccurate. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-manage-content 
In this instance, the Portal solution does not work.

Comment: ok, didn't know you were on a Mac :) I think I have found your problem, please check my previous answer, edited !

Comment: Finally - the answer!  Nicely done. The issue was the naming convention of the desired blob name. 
The example given in the Microsoft documentation is clearly wrong. Not sure how to get them to fix that, but; you're right - the Blob MUST have a valid extension.